# What are various methods for thread synchronisation in c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Apart from using lock(object) keyword, are there any fundamentally different or tricky or other useful in some situations ways to do syncronization ?

Comment: I am looking for brief summary which ones to use when. like rdwrtlock to sync rdr-wrtr pattern. semaphore to sync multiple accesses to resource etc. when to use interlocked (i think for atomic value type operations, not  fully sure..)

Comment: It would be more useful (to everyone) if you asked a specific question about a specific case.

Comment: getting downvote simply discourages one from asking further questions. it could have been closed simply with explanation. :(

Comment: I agree, the dv wasn't mine. But get used to it, downvotes on questions are free now.

Answer (score 1):

There are many classes in the [`Windows.Threading`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/798axes2.aspx) namespace.

[`Monitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx) and [`Mutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) being two important classes for synchronization within the namespace (there are others). `Lock` is syntactic sugar for simple `Monitor` operations.

[`Interlocked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) provides some thread safe operations (`Increment`, `Decrement` and more).

I suggest going through the MSDN documentation for the namespace and different classed in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to notify one thread of an event on a different thread, then `ManualResetEvent` and `AutoResetEvent` allow you to do so.

If you find that your code can handle simultaneous reads but need to synchronize writes, and your reading occurs much more frequently than your writes, then `ReaderWriterLock` (or now `ReaderWriterLockSlim`) will be of much help.

`Mutex` and `Semaphore` provide similar functionality to `lock()`, but can be used to synchronize across processes.

There are some others, but those are the three main others I typically use.

Answer (score 1):

The question is very broad.
There are books about different synchronization technics and which to use in which scenario.
There are a lot of different ways to do synchronization.

[Overview of Synchronization Primitives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228964.aspx)

Quite a few of new synchronization primitives where added in .NET 4. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460718.aspx

Comment: @Munish Goyal - any answer worked for you?